# Django REST with Celery daemon, no module named 'proj'

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, celeryd

I'm attempting to set up a `celery` daemon to run on server boot with a Django REST server (should note as well that I'm doing this all within a Vagrant VM). I've followed several tutorials online (including those provided by Celery) and still cannot get this to work.

Config:

```
CELERYD_NODES="celery_worker"
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="proj"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/vagrant/proj/"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

`proj/proj/celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

`proj/proj/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from proj.celery import app as celery_app
```

In my boot log, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 235, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 492, in symbol_by_name
    return symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'proj'
```

I cannot seem to get past this error despite having everything exactly the same as the Celery docs seem to want it. Any help out there?

Comment: were you able to figure it out?